# Collect /metrics Prometheus in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, prometheus, monitoring, azure-container-apps

I'm starting with Azure Container Apps, and I have a question:

All my applications issue a /metrics endpoint that my Prometheus server consumes.

I configured it for 5 instances of container apps. Soon I will have 5 applications running in parallel.

myapplication.com/metrics

Whenever my prometheus accesses /metrics it should collect a different metric due to traffic balancing.

How can I integrate the /metrics export with the average of the 5 container instances via prometheus?

I know that with Kubernetes it is possible, but I intend to use Azure Container Apps.

Comment: I believe, Azure Container Apps supports deploying container instances in parallel and integrating with Prometheus for collecting metrics.